# Salesforce1 App for Apple Watch

Tags: salesforce1-app, analytics, salesforce1-applewatch

I'm looking for information on whether Salesforce1 app is available for Apple Watch. The [website](http://www.salesforce.com/applewatch/) suggests it is available but if I look at the [App Store link](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id404249815?mt=8), it does not list Apple Watch in supported devices.

There are other apps like Salesforce Analytics which are listed as supported on Apple Watch on [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/salesforce-analytics/id916982402?mt=8).

I will eventually reach out to Salesforce support for it as well but posted it here just in case anyone has any concrete inputs to offer.

Answer (score 4):

As of today for Salesforce1 Mobile, there is no separate Apple Watch app that installs on the watch.

There is the default notification support which Apple Watch provides anyway.

There is the Wave/Analytics Cloud app that you mention.

There is also an [Apple Watch project](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting-Started-With-Apple-Watch-Devkit) that can be found in a repo on the developerforce github account. I played with it...but never managed to get it properly working.

That covers everything that I am aware of today.